# Spring AOP: advice is not triggered

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

Trying to design simple aspect,that will print word "logg" to console,when any of public methods executed.

**aspect:**

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicServices() {
    };

    @Before("publicServices()")
    public void logg() {
        System.out.println("logg");
    }

}
```

**xml config**:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="aspectlogging" /> 
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <bean id="loggingAspectHolder" class="aspectlogging.LoggingAspect"/>
```

**simple bean:**

```
package aspectlogging;
@Component
    public class TestableBean {

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        }
```

**test:**

```
public class TestLogging {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestableBean tb = new TestableBean();
        tb.setName("yes");
        tb.getName();
    }
}
```

I expect,that result of running of `TestLogging` will be "**logg**" word in console,and no output returned.
Do I understand AOP correctly in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `@Around` advice, you need to have a `ProceedingJoinPoint pjp` argument to the advising method and to call `pjp.proceed()` at the point in the advisor when you want the wrapped method to be called. It's easier to use `@Before` advice really, when what you've done will otherwise work just fine.

---

[EDIT]: Also, you *must* let Spring construct your beans for you instead of directly calling `new`. This is because the bean object is actually a proxy for your real object (which sits inside it). Because your target object doesn't implement an interface, you will need to have the cglib library on your classpath in addition to the Spring libraries. (Alternatively, you can go with using AspectJ fully, but that requires using a different compiler configuration.)

To create your beans, you first need to create a Spring *context* and then query that for the bean instance. This means you change from:

```
TestableBean tb = new TestableBean();
```

To (assuming you're using Spring 3, and that your XML config is in "config.xml" somewhere on your classpath):

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
TestableBean tb = context.getBean(TestableBean.class);
```

The rest of your code remains the same (after adjusting for `import` statements and possibly additional dependencies).

Comment: Whoops; just noticed the elephant in the room. Let Spring make the beans so that it can weave its magic spell for you; don't do it yourself.

Comment: Donal,do you mean I needn't call getBean() from context manually?

Comment: @sergionni: I mean, don't do 'new Blah()`, do `context.getBean(Blah.class)`. You don't do direct object construction with Spring, you use Spring as your object factory (assuming you want those objects to be beans; non-beans you can make any way you want).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, if you intend to autowire this with Spring, you will need your aspect to be annotated with `@Component` or `@Service`.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure on this one, but maybe you need to use a spring managed TestableBean to have spring AOP pick up the method call.

edit: of course, you can't use `@Around` the way that you provided - but this subject has been addressed by another answer, so it's omitted here.

edit2: If you need help on how to get a spring managed bean, please feel free to ask. but since you already got your aspect bean set up, I believe you can handle this :)

edit3: Hehe. Ok.. maybe not :)

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

will load your application context.
Load beans from there by calling:

```
TestableBean testableBean = (TestableBean )ctx.getBean("testableBean ");
```

Define the `TestableBean` just like you did with your Aspect bean.

edit4: Now I'm pretty sure that the fault is the non-spring managed bean.

`Use the simplest thing that can work. Spring AOP is simpler than using full AspectJ as there is no requirement to introduce the AspectJ compiler / weaver into your development and build processes. If you only need to advise the execution of operations on Spring beans, then Spring AOP is the right choice. If you need to advise domain objects, or any other object not managed by the Spring container, then you will need to use AspectJ.`

Taken from: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: do you mean ,that I should specify TestableBean in xml config or declare it as @Service?

Comment: i'm afraid,that it's not flexible, as far i'm going my aspects will be used by a lot of classes

Comment: Please give it a try first. If this is the solution we can find a way how to make this more 'flexible'. There are many different ways on how to have spring pickup your beans. For example: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/seemarich/archive/2007/11/annotation_base.html

Comment: Yes,i understand about bean from context.And the matter is if I will use this aspect as lib,and external project would like to plug it,so they need to specify all beans in config?I treat this AOP as a listener,which listens any public method and log some result when return value got.

Comment: see my edit4. it's not possible to use Spring AOP on non-spring managed beans. use full aspectj for that.

Comment: do you mean ,that i should annotate my bean appropriately, e.g. @Service?

Comment: Please have a look at the spring documentation on how to create spring managed beans. annotations are one way to go, yes. Before we go more into that matter, could you please confirm that this solved your problem?

Comment: As I understand, Service annotation is alternative to xml config <bean id> declaration.I've tried @Service annotation,didn't help.

Comment: You need to re-write your applicationContext in order to have spring scan for these annotations. PLEASE have a look at the spring reference. For testing purposes, you could just define it in your xml.

Comment: i've updated post - added package and scan param to .xml and tag to bean,strange,it didn't help me

Comment: Because you're not getting the spring-managed bean in your main class.
See edit3 and read the reference documentation

Comment: But you're not using the spring version. I can't stress anymore how much you need to read the documentation.

Comment: Why you think,that I'm not using Sping version? I specified @Service annotation for the bean and context:component-scan in xml descriptor.Perhaps,I don't understand your point here.

Comment: actually,i've managed do it with:ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/java/aspectlogging/web-application-config.xml"); But it doesn' i need.I need't getBean()
  
  TestableBean tb = (TestableBean) ctx.getBean("testableBean");

Comment: try:
public class TestLogging {
    @Autowired
    private TestableBean tb;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tb.setName("yes");